# Create Squential data from a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I have a huge table like this:

```
id   eventid timestamp
id1  event1  time1
id1  event2  time2
id2  event1  time3
id2  event4  time4
id1  event4  time6
```

What I want is for each user, its events sorted by time like this:

```
id     event_sequence(nvarchar)
id1    event1,event2,event4
id2    event1,event4
```

Is there a SQL query I can do this in Postgres (Greenplum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  I don't know if you can do this in Greenplum.  In Postgres, it would look like:

```
select id, string_agg(event, ',' order by timestamp) as events
from t
group by id;
```

In Greenplum, I think you need to use:

```
select id, array_to_string(array_agg(event, ',' order by timestamp)) as events
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: The first one works in GreenPlum. Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.